# Poor video playback performance on Aspire One 752

Tags: 15.04, video, mate, gpu-driver, aspire-one

I recently "upgraded" from windows 7 on the **Acer Aspire One 752** my wife bought a few years back. Given the state of that particular windows installation the machine is performing a lot better now that it is running Ubuntu MATE 15.04.

I do however have some problem with video playback. The system is unable to play mov-files recorded with our iphones. The CPU is nailed at 100% and VLC is able to produce something like 1 frame every 3 seconds.

My guess was that it was driver related, so after some googling I tried:

```
apt-get install i965-va-driver libvdpau-va-gl1 libva-glx1 libva-drm1 vainfo mpv
```

But playback is still as poor as it ever was.

Judging from the VLC settings I think hardware acceleration should be utilized, but it is probably still not.

[image: VLC settings]

I also tried adding:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="enable_mtrr_cleanup mtrr_spare_reg_nr=1"
```

to `/etc/default/grub` and running `sudo update-grub`to no avail.

I'm not entirely sure what graphics card is in the machine, but `lspci | grep -i vga` says:

```
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Mobile 4 Series Chipset Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 07)
```

`glxgears` is producing ~62 FPS, which I think is OK, so acceleration does not seem completely broken.

Youtube plays back a little bit stuttery, but it is atleast watchable. A great bit better than the mov-file playback.

I've also tried playing the mov-files using mpv with poor results.

Playing the files on my macbook works flawlessly, so the media in itself should be OK.

What else can I do to get playback working?

EDIT per Gannets suggestions:

```
$ sudo apt-get install libva-intel-vaapi-driver vainfo
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Note, selecting 'i965-va-driver' instead of 'libva-intel-vaapi-driver'
i965-va-driver is already the newest version.
vainfo is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
$ vainfo
libva info: VA-API version 0.37.0
libva info: va_getDriverName() returns 0
libva info: Trying to open /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/i965_drv_video.so
libva info: Found init function __vaDriverInit_0_37
libva info: va_openDriver() returns 0
vainfo: VA-API version: 0.37 (libva 1.5.0)
vainfo: Driver version: Intel i965 driver for Intel(R) GM45 Express Chipset - 1.5.0
vainfo: Supported profile and entrypoints
      VAProfileMPEG2Simple            : VAEntrypointVLD
      VAProfileMPEG2Main              : VAEntrypointVLD
$ mpv -vo vaapi -hwdec=vaapi ~/Desktop/file.mov 
Playing: /home/user/Desktop/file.mov
 (+) Video --vid=1 (*) (h264)
 (+) Audio --aid=1 --alang=und (*) (aac)
libva info: VA-API version 0.37.0
libva info: va_getDriverName() returns 0
libva info: Trying to open /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/i965_drv_video.so
libva info: Found init function __vaDriverInit_0_37
libva info: va_openDriver() returns 0
Trying to use hardware decoding.
AO: [pulse] 44100Hz mono 1ch float
[vaapi] Decoder profile 'VAProfileH264High' not available.
[libav/video] h264: decode_slice_header error
[vaapi] Decoder profile 'VAProfileH264High' not available.
[libav/video] h264: decode_slice_header error
[libav/video] h264: no frame!
Error while decoding frame!
Error using hardware decoding, falling back to software decoding.
VO: [vaapi] 1920x1080 yuv420p
AV: 00:00:00 / 00:03:22 (0%) A-V:  0.471 Dropped: 4


           *************************************************
           **** Audio/Video desynchronisation detected! ****
           *************************************************

This means either the audio or the video is played too slowly.
Possible reasons, problems, workarounds:
- Your system is simply too slow for this file.
     Transcode it to a lower bitrate file with e.g. mpv encoding support.
- Slow video output.
     Try a different --vo driver (--vo=help for a list). Make sure framedrop
     is not disabled, or experiment with different values for --framedrop.
- Playing from a slow network source.
     Download the file instead.
- Try to find out whether audio/video/subs are causing this by experimenting
  with --no-video, --no-audio, or --no-sub.
- If you switched audio or video tracks, try seeking to force synchronization.
If none of this helps you, file a bug report.

AV: 00:00:03 / 00:03:22 (1%) A-V:  5.831 Dropped: 42


Exiting... (Quit)
```

Works no better, but clearly states that hardware acceleration is failing.

Answer (score 1):

If you wanna try/determine hardware acceleration for video playback you should install:

```
apt-get install libva-intel-vaapi-driver vainfo
```

Then run:

```
vainfo
```

You'll see supported acceleration modes. Then, IMHO, the best player to try is mpv:

```
mpv -vo vaapi -hwdec=vaapi some_video.mkv
```

In player output you'll se if acceleration is working by

```
Using hardware acceleration
```

line.

For youtube make sure it plays through HTML5 (instead of shitty flash) by turning it on on a [youtube.com/html5](http://youtube.com/html5) page.

Also try to turning on hardware acceleration for your browser. How to depends on which browser you're using.

Comment: -vo vaapi is not recommended anymore: https://github.com/mpv-player/mpv/blob/master/DOCS/man/vo.rst